# Are there smart contracts in Etherium that can be called to buy other cryptocurrencies?

Tags: api, ethereum, solidity, exchange-server

I want to buy Arweave coins when my contract solidety payable function is called. So I wonder are there any Smart Contracts with solidety API that provide exchange services?

I look for a function like: `buy('wallet_address_to_transfer_coins_to_on_other_network', 'token_mnemonic', Amount);` function that can be called within my solidety payable function and could for example sequre tokens for NFT data storedge space.

So are there cryptocurrency exchanges with solidity API?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the tokens in other chain maybe you could try with a bridge, if not you could try with any dex in which the coin you want is listed, or maybe you could need both for the thing you want to

Comment: The main question for me is which dex  can be integrated within my payable function so that when user calls my function he pays and “performs” exchange?

Comment: any dex that operates in your target chain, maybe uniswap, sushiswap, or any other one, I don't know what will be the chain were you are going to deploy

Comment: can you provide a link to any (maybe uniswap, sushiswap, or any other one) dex that provides a documented **solidity** API (not JS one)?

Comment: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/single-swaps